# How do I register OIDs under my PEN?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, mib

I have read multiple tutorials and walkthroughs for creating MIBs, and creating/running subagents but I am repeatedly faced with "No Such Instance currently exists at this OID" when performing a *walk* or *get*.

I can post my current code/MIBs if needed, but I would appreciate if someone with experience in (Net-)SNMP could provide a brief walkthrough of the essential steps for getting one's PEN to be recognized by `snmpwalk`, `snmpget`, and `snmpset` etc. (without the use of the `extend` or `pass` commands in *snmpd.conf*).

Thanks!

**NOTES:**
When running `sudo make install` (after `./configure --with-mib-modules="myModules"`), I notice that my MIB is never installed by *libtool* during the installation sequence.
i.e. This never happens:

```
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./MY-CUSTOM-MIB.txt /usr/local/share/snmp/mibs/MY-CUSTOM-MIB.txt
install: installed MY-CUSTOM-MIB.txt in /usr/local/share/snmp/mibs
```